# How to add dynamic Spinner's as well as remove them?

Tags: android, dynamic, android-spinner, reminders

My question revolves around reminder `Spinner`'s. I am trying to allow the user to add at maximum, 5 reminders. But I also don't want to show all five. These reminders are each `Spinner`'s which have multiple choices. When the user clicks to add a reminder, it will do so. When they want to take one away, they can do that as well, and when they want to add another one, the new one appears at the bottom. Any idea of how to go about this?

My original implementation was to have 5 already defined (4 "gone"), but then if the user wants to add one, it becomes "visible". Problem with that is that if you take away a reminder from the view by making it "gone", and add it back, it does not apear at the bottom, but rather back where it originally was (unless it was already the last spinner). Now I am lost as to how to dynamically add spinners specifically under certain views. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Edit: what I have so far/ **RemindersAdapter.java**

---

```
public class RemindersAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
ArrayList<Spinner> shownReminders;

public RemindersAdapter(Context c) {
    shownReminders.add(new Spinner(c));
    shownReminders.add(new Spinner(c));
    shownReminders.add(new Spinner(c));
    shownReminders.add(new Spinner(c));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return shownReminders.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return shownReminders.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reminder_spinner, parent, false);
    }
    Log.d("TAG", "This is trying to run");
    Spinner reminderSpinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.duplicate_reminder);
    reminderSpinner.setTag("1"); //this tag will be used to check which it is and correctly put the reminder into its respective String
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> reminderAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            parent.getContext(), R.array.reminders_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    reminderAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    reminderSpinner.setAdapter(reminderAdapter);
    reminderSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnReminderSelectedListener());
    shownReminders.add(position, reminderSpinner);


    return view;
}


/*
 * Listener for when the reminder spinner gets a value the user entered
 * */
public class MyOnReminderSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener{

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        //does nothing for now

    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // Do nothing for now   
    }   
}//end of MyOnReminderSelectedListener innerclass
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of data appearance in the spinner is based on the order of the data you feed into the adapter.  If you want to change the order of the display you need to change the order in the data backing the adapter (and use `notifyDataSetChanged()` to make the spinner re-draw).

Without seeing code it's difficult to know how to tell you to proceed further.

Comment: I am having trouble setting it up. Like I am not really sure how to correctly do it. I am using a `ListView` extending a `BaseAdapter`, but its not working. The hardest part for me is adding a dynamic `Spinner`.